# Conclude that $\frac{1}N\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n\to 0$ almost surely (without using strong law of large numbers)

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, martingales

Given a sequence of IID random variables with expectation zero and finite variance, $X_1,X_2,...$

> Prove that $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{X_n}{n}$ is a martingale, and
>   conclude that $\frac{1}N\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n\to 0$ almost surely using
>   [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087808/slick-proofs-that-if-sum-limits-k-1-infty-fraca-kk-converges-then-l)

So for showing that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{X_n}{n}$ is a martingale I think I got it right:

$E[S_{N}|S_1,...,S_{N-1}]=E[\frac{X_N}{N}+S_{N-1}|S_1,...,S_{N-1}]=E[\frac{X_N}{N}|S_1,...,S_{N-1}]+E[S_{N-1}|S_1,...,S_{N-1}]=\frac{1}{N}E[X_N]+S_{N-1}=0+S_{N-1}=S_{N-1}$

For the second part  though I'm not sure, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result follows immediately by the strong law of large numbers. The law states that for a sequence of iid random variables with finite mean,
\begin{align*}
P(\lim_n \bar{X}_n = EX) = 1
\end{align*}
i.e. the empirical mean $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ converges almost surely to $EX=0$.

To show it using the linked exercise, we invoke the Martingale Convergence Theorem on $\{S_n\}$ so that $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{X_n}{n}$ converges. Then by the linked exercise, the empirical average converges to 0.

To show the sufficient condition for MCT, namely that $\sup_N E|S_N| < \infty$, observe that
\begin{align*}
Var|S_N| &= Var\Big|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{X_n}{n} \Big| \\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}Var|X_n| \\
&= Var|X_1| \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty
\end{align*}
by assumption. Since $Var|S_N| = E(S_N^2) - (ES_N)^2 = E(S_N^2) - 0 = E(S_N^2)$, we have that the measurable function $S_N$ is in $L^2$. Since the probability measure is finite, $S_N$ is also an element of $L^1$. Thus, $E|S_N| < \infty$.

Comment: I know it follows from the law of large numbers, but I need to prove it using the exercise I linked, do you know how?

Comment: use MCT. see my edit

Comment: I see, though checking the conditions for the MCT, it says that $supE(|S_N|)$ must be bounded, is it because of the finite variance?

Comment: well $E(S_N) = \sum_1^N E(X_i / i) = 0$, so it follows by the mean of $X$ being 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, the condition has the $S_N$ in absolute value so I'm not sure it works, unless the definition for the MCT is different from what I see

Comment: oops! sorry, yeah it follows by finite variance, and the fact that the series $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. see my edit